Get data from P6 EPPM API using Python with response 401
I am trying to retrieve data from P6 EPPM API following their documentation as per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F51301_01/English/Integration_Documentation/rest_api/index.html
I am using PySpark in Microsoft Fabric as I need to ingest the data to data warehouse. I have got P6 Cloud login with admin access and API license however when I was trying to call the REST API, it keeps throwing response 401 error.
My code is as per below:

import requests


def getAccessToken():
 username = 'XXXXXX'
 password = 'XXXXX'
 credentials = f"{username}:{password}"
 b64_credentials = base64.b64encode(credentials.encode()).decode()
 headers = {'token_exp':'3600','authToken': b64_credentials}
 url = 'https://XXXXX/p6ws/oauth/token'
 response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
 api_response = response.content.decode('UTF-8')
 accesstoken = api_response.replace('\n','')
 return (accesstoken)

def getDataFromP6eppm():
  headersAPI = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken()
  }
 
  response = requests.get('https://XXXXX/p6ws/restapi/project?',headers = headersAPI)
  
  return(response)

getDataFromP6eppm()

The first function getAccessToken() has connected successfully with response[200] however getDataFromP6eppm() doesnt like it with 401 response, anyone could help?
